# ASP.NET MVC + AngularJs + Bootstrap

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

Estoy trabajando con ASP.NET MVC 4.

Tengo unas dudas, al instalar Angulars **¿hay un Bootstrap para Angulars?**, oh no tiene que ver uno con el otro, **¿la instalación de ambos es independiente?**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bootstrap y AngularJs son dos Frameworks diferentes coexisten sin ningún problema. hacen cosas diferentes que se complementan.
Bootstrap es un framework desarrollado y liberado por Twitter que tiene como objetivo facilitar el diseño web
AngularJS es un framework MVC de JavaScript para el Desarrollo Web Front End que permite crear aplicaciones SPA Single-Page Applications.

Usted puede invocarlos desde el html con una linea asi:

```html
 src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js">
```

y para Boostrap:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"> src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js">
```

O si esta trabajando con Visual Studio puede instalarlo como un Nuget para el proyecto.

Sugiero mirar estas Url:
http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/default.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_default&stacked=h

Answer (score 4):

AngularJS y Bootstrap son dos cosas diferentes. El primero es un framework javascript que no toma decisiones en cuanto al diseño de tu sitio. El segundo es un framework responsive y mobile-first para el front-end que te da unas cuantas herramientas utiles como un sistema de rejilla y una gran cantidad de estilos y componentes listos para usarse.

El problema surge porque bootstrap usa jquery lo cual no siempre coincide con el flujo de AngularJS y te obliga a estar creando directivas para adaptarlas.

Si lo que quieres es usar ambos en un proyecto te recomiendo que descargues [ui-boostrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) que son las directivas de bootstrap para AngularJS.

Luego de seguir las [instrucciones de instalación](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/getting_started) debes incluir el módulo con

```
angular.module('myModule', ['ui.bootstrap']);
```

y ya puedes usar ambos frameworks con un mínimo de fricción.

Comment: Se instala ui-boostrap, después de haber instalado Boostrap.